# How to save translated Properties file as right-to-left?

Tags: javascript, properties, localization

I have a translation of a properties file into Pashto and Dari. Does anyone know how I can save this file to read the content as right-to-left?

I know I am able to toggle to read it right to left in Notepad editor, but I need the raw data to be set to right-to-left.

Thanks in advance!
Stephanie

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that JS has a native way of reading files from right to left.

As a workaround, you could try to create a new string that will be the reversed version of the string you just read.

```
function reverseWord(x) {
 return x.split("").reverse().join("")
}
```

So, when you're preparing the file to be saved and you want to iterate through all of the lines, add the reverseWord function into the loop.

There may be custom libraries that help with this.